# Assistance in understanding the following methods: request.query_string

Tags: ruby

I've tried searching both the site and the Ruby docs, however, I am unable to find a clear answer to exactly what the above is doing.

From what I understand, 'request' and 'query_string' are two separate methods, however I'm really unsure what they do - the latter in particular.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Is this in a Rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, the #request method available in controllers and views returns a ActionDispatch::Request instance. The Request object allows access to data from the HTTP Request.

The #query_string method, defined in Rack::Request::Helpers, returns the query string from the request url. This is the part in the url following the "?" which specifies url encoded data in the format key=value&other_key=other_value.

***Note:***

ActionDispatch::Request is a Rails class that behaves similarly to a Rack::Request, including Rack::Request::Env and Rack::Request::Helpers in the current version of Rails v 5.0. In previous versions ActionDispatch::Request inherited directly from Rack::Request.

***Read more:***

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html
- https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb

Comment: Thanks, man! I must say though that I noticed the use of 'require' in Sinatra - I imagine the same rules apply though? Thanks again. :)

Comment: It looks like Sinatra's Request object directly inherits from Rack::Request (https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L23). In Ruby, #require loads a library from the load path (only once), include (such as what is done with Rack::Request::Helpers in ActionDispatch::Request) appends a Module to the ancestor chain, making instance methods available.